# dateObj.getMonth() not working in nativescript

Tags: nativescript

I am trying to get the month from the date object . But I am getiing error whci displays says "getMonth is not a function".
Since I saw some Java script tutorials , where getMonth() is supported in ES6.
Am I missing importing anything.

```
 var config = require("../../shared/config");
 var fetchModule = require("fetch");
 var ObservableArray = require("data/observable-array").ObservableArray;
 var datePickerModule = require("tns-core-modules/ui/date-picker");

 function TaskListViewModel(items){
   var listModel = new ObservableArray(items);

   listModel.getTaskList = function()
   {
    return fetchModule.fetch(config.TaskListURL,{
        method:"Get"            
    })
    .then(handleErrors)
    .then(function(response){
        return response.json();
    }).then(function(data) {
        data.forEach(function(element) {
            var dateObj = Date.parse(element.followUpDate)
            listModel.push({
                fallowUpDateMonth:dateObj.getMonth(),
                faloowUpDateDay:dateObj.getDate(),
                fallowupDateYear:dateObj.getFullYear(),
            });

        });
    });

};

     return listModel;
 }


 module.exports = TaskListViewModel;
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `fallowUpDateMonth:dateObj.getMonth()`?

Comment: Are you sure the `dateObj` is parsed correctly? What is its result? What is its JavaScript type?

Comment: element.followUpDate is "2017-03-05"
dateObj is 1488672000000

Comment: So you are using the Date API incorrectly. The dateObj is a string of milliseconds, and not a Date object which to execute methods on. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse

Comment: Yea .. That works. Thank you very much @ pkanev